# Add alert or action sheet to UITableView during swiping to delete

Tags: iphone

I want to pass an object to the action sheet from the declaration of the UIActionSheet, how to do it?

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger) buttonIndex{
```

Comment: What does it mean by "pass an object to the from..."? I just don't get it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a property in your header.
2. Set it whenever you create your
   object.
3. Then reference it in the
       didDismissWithButotnIndex you
       posted.

Easy. Peasy. Japanesy.

Comment: Well, it does the job. Is it a good design? Or a best practice?

Comment: I don't think there is any other way. You can declare the properties private so they don't get exposed to outside classes.